# LDAP: Fetch users under a OU using ad explorer

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm using adexplorer to query an LDAP directory. I would like to fetch all users that have a certain OU in their DN. So I tried:

[image]

The results returns an OU, even though I picked class:user. How do I findusers who have a certain OU in their DN?

Comment: Is there a reason for using ADExplorer, and not a CLI?  That's what I'd try next.... use dsquery or the PowerShell cmdlets to make your query, see if that doesn't work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> fetch all users that have a certain OU in their DN

Unfortunately, searches with wildcards for the Distinguised Names values are not permitted in Microsoft AD.
Also, the "OU" attribute is not auto populated for user objects. The OU attribute is only auto popluated on OU objects.

To reach your goal you need to either

1. Query all users in the entire domain and filter that full result set on the client side or
2. Make multiple queries with a scripted query tool.
3. If you know there is only one OU you want to query, and that will never change, you can make a single query with `searchbase` set.

Part 1 of the multi query method enumerates OU's with the desired name. Part 2 runs a second query where the search base is each of those paths, and the filter is (objectCategory=user). In Powershell you could do it like this:

```
Import-Module -name ActiveDirectory
get-adobject -ldapFilter "(&(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(ou=SOMENAME))" | foreach {
    get-aduser -searchscope oneLevel -searchbase $_.distinguishedName -ldapfilter "(objectCategory=user)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use dsquery

```
dsquery user "OU=Users_MSS_DAL,OU=...,OU=com"
```

to find the distingished OU-Name (if uncertain):

```
dsquery ou domainroot  -name "*MSS*"
```

to find just the OU of one user:

```
dsquery user -name "*lastname*"
```

(replace lastname with real lastname)

Make sure to use 2 wildcards, like "*MSS*" - otherwise the search might return nothing